# Proof that equality is symmetric in Coq

Tags: coq

I am just starting with Coq and right now trying to prove some stuff that is in "The Little Prover".
One of the theorems I came across is the following:

```
Theorem equal_swap : forall (A: Type) (x:A) (y:A),
    (x = y) = (y = x).
```

However, I am unable to prove this. I tried finding out how to rewrite the right side of the equation with eq_sym, but I am unable to apply it to only one expression of the goal.

How would I go about proving this theorem?

Comment: Actually this is not provable, you may want to prove the `<->` version.

Comment: Why isn't this provable? so (x=y)<->(y=x)?

Comment: What you are stating is that the two proofs of equality are the same, and this is not always the case for example if you interpret equality as paths [as done in HoTT]

Comment: You can however prove `(x == y) = (y == x)` or `(x = y) <-> (y = x)`, both proofs are easy and can be done with standard tactics. [a == b is the boolean version of eq]

Comment: @ejgallego He rather states that the two equalities are the same, which, I believe, is even stronger.

Comment: Stronger than what @eponier?

Comment: @ejgallego you said "you are stating that the two proofs of equality are the same", which is not what he wrote. He wrote that the two propositions are the same. I think this is what eponier was alluding to (though I am not sure there is any relationship between the two statements).

Comment: @ejgallego As Arthur said, the question is about equality of propositions, not about proof irrelevance. I was thinking of `ext_prop_dep_proof_irrel_cic : prop_extensionality -> proof_irrelevance`, but finally I am not sure if this theorem (or a variant of it) can be used in this context.

Comment: I actually wanted to proof that the equality boolean equality is reflexive. (so arguably sth quite simple if I am correct.) In that case I would need to use (x==y) = (y==x) correct?

Comment: ```
What you are stating is that the two proofs of equality are the same, and this is not always the case for example if you interpret equality as paths [as done in HoTT]``` this actually helps in understanding; 
so ```x = y``` in coq means to compare proofs for the propositions x and y instead of value, etc. comparisions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that Coq uses pervasively is the concept of "propositions as types".  Intuitively, types are collections of objects.  So what are the elements of these collections?  They are proofs.  A proposition that is provable is a type that contains an element, a proposition that is not provable is a type that does not contain a proof.

So `a = b` is a type, a type of proofs and `b = a` is also a type of proofs but they don't prove the same statement.  The purpose of the logic in Coq is to be very precise about statements.  Can we say that `a = b` and `b = a` are the same?  Well, in a sense they are not.  If I have a goal of the form `C(a, b)` and I rewrite with a proof of `a = b` then I obtain `C(a, a)`  and if I rewrite with a proof of `b = a` then I obtain `C(b, b)` and these two don't look the same.  One make argue that they are the same (because `a` and `b` are the same by assumption) but one may also argue that they are not the same (because you don't use them in the same manner).

When designing a logical system like Coq, it turns out that you can do a lot of logic even if you don't try to talk about equality between propositions, but concentrate yourself on just using equivalence between propositions.  So people tried to add the least amount of properties to the concept of *equality*.  In particular, equality between types was left naked.  You will see that equality is practical to use when talking about equality between first-order data, it is less convenient when talking about higher-order data (like equality between functions), and it is awkward when talking about equality between types.

On the other hand, if they want to study the relation between two propositions, they only try to check whether one proposition implies another one, and if they want to be more precise, they try to see if they imply each other mutually.  For most practical purposes this will be enough, and I suggest you stick to this discipline as long as you consider yourself a beginner.

Here, we may want to prove `a = b -> b = a`.  If we do this as a proof using tactics, then `intro` will help us give a name to `a = b` (say `H`) and `rewrite H` will help us transform `b = a` into `a = a`.  Now the last proof can be done by reflexivity.  But when I say transform `b = a` into `a = a`.  I only mean that `a = a -> b = a` has a proof, in other words "there is a function, when given as input a proof of `a = a`, it produces as output a proof of `b = a`.  When performing a proof, we have the impression that the proof of `a = a` is transformed into a proof of `b = a` while staying the same, but it is not: two different proofs are observed here.

In the end, `(a = b) <-> (b = a)` is just the conjunction of `(a = b) -> (b = a)` and `(b = a) -> (a = b)`.  The `rewrite` tactic has also been extended so that you can also rewrite with a theorem is an equivalence, instead of an equality.

Comment: This is a magnificent answer, that helped me understand a lot more, thx; I knew that Coq makes use as propositions as types but I couldn't unify that with the proper useage of the = operator.

Comment: The `rewrite` tactic does not only work for equality statement.  You can also use `rewrite th` if theorem `th` has a statement that expresses an equivalence.  This because `rewrite` has been extended to handle a more general class of equivalence relations.